# Measuring "Watch Time" for a video platform

Tags: postgresql, algorithm, time-series, analytics, recommendation-engine

I have a video sharing service and I'm trying to track the watch time to provide recommendations. I have two questions here:

1. What's a good way to measure this? One I've seen around the web is to send a tick every 10 seconds and increment some counter, but this seems very inelegant.
2. How should this data be stored for processing an analytics? Should each user's view of a video be a row in my postgres database for example? And the watchtime is incremented on that row as a series of 10s ticks? `timespent:5` = 50s?

Comment: Do you have starttime and endtime for one session. You can log the endtime as soon as the session ends and then you will have the watch time or consecutive watchtimes.

Comment: @VarunT this unfortunately would mean that a user that skips to the end of an hour long video immediately would be marked as viewing the whole thing. Same thing if they jump backwards.

Comment: I see. Yes. I missed that. For the analytics part, may be you can have duration categories as columns with a 1 or 0.  Like upto_1_min , upto_2_min , upto_3_min and mark them as 0 or 1 depending if they have reached that limit.

Comment: 1. You can check which frames are sent to the user and assume that 90% of these frames are viewed (10% are for buffer), than you can tell how much time is viewed. 2. You can use quantiles to do smarter discretization.